# How to get diff for single changeset?

Tags: mercurial

Running `hg diff -r XXXX` seems to compare that changeset with my local copy. How do I get just the changes for that changeset compared to the one it was built off of, like you would see on BitBucket or GitHub?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
hg diff -c XXXX
```

You can specify `-c`/`--change` with a revision to see the changes in that changeset relative to its first parent ([source](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#commands)).

Comment: This still isn't consistent in what I'm seeing in the web preview diff.

Comment: @Mark - change web-frontend